# How to compare 2 datasets in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and have been given a task to compare 2 csv files in spark java. I am creating the 2 datasets from those csv files. I have to compare using the key and display the output as to which value is different and for what field. Could someone please help. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.except(df1)`

This function can compare 2 dataset, it will return a new dataset containing rows in df but not in df1.

Comment: Thanks. I tried ds1.except(ds2); it only gets us to the rows that have discrepancies. Do we need to use core Java to further identify individual columns cells where the datasets differ? For eg, given ds1 with 10 cols & 50 rows; ds2 with 10 cols (same col names) with 50 rows and a common "column_id" which can be used as a key to join these datasets. Assuming values in "Column_A" are different between both datasets, the final result should look like,
column_id    column_A_ds1     column_A_ds2
Abcd_123          3564                     3565
Defg_123           8796                     7796

Comment: Or you can just join two tables?  before join table, you should better change column a name, ds1 column_a to column_a_ds1 and ds2 column_a to column_a_ds2. `val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("column_id"))` and then filter df3, `where ("column_a_ds1 != column_a_ds2")`